# Initialisation error

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

Anyone have any idea why this works:

```
int main(void)
{
char action;
int *i;
*i=10;
printf("%d",*i);
action='C';
printf("%c",action);
}
```

but this doesnt

```
int main(void)
{
char action='C';
int *i;
*i=10;
printf("%d",*i);
printf("%c",action);
}
```

I am getting no errors but it will not run! cant see why that little difference makes it crash

Comment: `*i=10;` is dereferencing an uninitialised pointer, that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: The code is correct in both the versions. Please give further details like compiler, environment, platform,etc.

Comment: @askmish - Actually code is wrong in both versions.

Comment: Why the down vote? It's not actually my own question, but I thought it was an interesting problem which I myself couldn't answer (glad I didn't advise the individual in question to post on Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Its not wrong. The uninitialized pointer by default always contains a garbage value. The garbage value might be an user accessible address or not. So, its undefined behavior on part of the code execution. But, syntactically its right and valid(even though its bad).

Comment: @askmish: Firstly, to say that it "contains a value" (even a garbage one) would be misleading. An uninitialized variable is not guaranteed to hold a stable specific value, i.e. multiple reads of the same uninitialized variable can "see" different values. Secondly, undefined behavior is not a "part of the code execution". The compiler is allowed to reject a program that produces UB. The above program is non-compilable in formal general case. The code is wrong.

Comment: @askmish Undefined behavior is undefined. See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 and http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `undefined bahavior`.
You have created a pointer and without initializing the pointer, you are directly putting the value `10` to the memory location pointed to by pointer `i` where `i` has `indeterminate value`.So, in that case it will put the value `10` to that garbage value location (the value of pointer `i`). So it may execute if garbage value location is accessible or may crash if memory location is not accessible.

Hence it's just `undefined bahavior`

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of your code is undefined. There's no logic in its behavior. It is essentially random. Trying to analyze why some irrelevant "little difference" changes the behavior you observed in your experiments is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Both your programs are equally wrong as indicated by other answers.

Many ways to make it correct. Here are 2 ways.

1. ```
   int *i;
   int j;
   i = &j;
   *i = 10;
   ```
2. ```
   int * i = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *i = 10;

   // After you are done with i

   free(i);
   ```